# I can't upload file to one drive using c#

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, azure-ad-graph-api

I get an error 400 Bad Request when I try to upload a file to my OneDrive using the Microsoft Graph API

- GetAccessToken method get the access token
- upload method take the file path and upload it to my OneDrive account

  ```
  public class OneDrive
  {

   public void Upload(string filePath)
   {

       var token = GetAccessToken();
       var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root:/test/test.pdf:/content";
       PostRequest(url, token, filePath).Wait();
   }
   public string GetAccessToken()
   {
       var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("client id ")
             .WithClientSecret("client secret")
               .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/v2.0")
             .Build();
       string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
       try
       {
           var result = app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync().Result;
           Console.WriteLine(result.TenantId); 
           return result.AccessToken;
       }
       catch (MsalServiceException ex) when (ex.Message.Contains("AADSTS70011"))
       {
           Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
           return null;
       }
   }
   public async Task PostRequest(string webApiUrl, string accessToken, string filePath)
   {

       HttpContent content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath)));
       HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
       {
           var defaultRequestHeaders = httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;
           httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));


           defaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

           HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PutAsync(webApiUrl, content);
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
               Console.WriteLine("File Successfuly Uploaded");
           else
               Console.WriteLine("Error Occur");
       }
   }
  }
  ```

Comment: Does the HTTP 400 accompany a message?

Comment: Check the returned error message. You can check that via `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsysn()` method.

Comment: I got this error on response {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Unable to retrieve tenant service info.","innerError":{"date":"2021-06-12T18:48:30","request-id":"03fd16e1-7039-4e98-aa87-7c365d745fe5","client-request-id":"03fd16e1-7039-4e98-aa87-7c365d745fe5"}}}

Answer (score 0):

After removing this line :

`httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));`

Your code works perfectly for me:
[image]

There is no need to set `accpet` header in request.

Comment: i got the same error after i remove the line ee {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Unable to retrieve tenant service info.","innerError":{"date":"2021-06-14T08:01:33","request-id":"cbaacdd8-4ce4-47b8-a85e-9a207f7aa4c0","client-request-id":"cbaacdd8-4ce4-47b8-a85e-9a207f7aa4c0"}}} 0